# SQL Server bad performance per server

Tags: sql-server, performance, memory-management, configuration, installation

I have a .NET Windows application that runs large number of inserts in a SQL SERVER 2008 R2 database .

When I run the application on my laptop(also the database is on my laptop) it works fine.
But when I run it on a sever that is absolutely better than my loptop in any cases, it works at least 5 times slower.

In both case , databases are the same, applications are the same and data are the same .

what are the things that could effect on SQL Server performance (except for T-SQL )?

Comment: Are you using SQL Server 2008 Express version? Even though you have a high end machine, SQL Express 2008 would take only 1GB of RAM. Also check the CPU/memory utilization.

Comment: In both Case I'm using SQL SERVER 2008 R2.
In the server computer I think SQL SERVER configured to have unlimited memory so it takes about 23 gigabytes of 24 gigabytes RAM of server.

Answer (score 0):

Uhhhhhhhh, a few things come to mind:

1. How do you know it's not a network issue?
2. What happens when you run some queries directly on an SSMS window in the server?
3. Are there other apps collocated on that server? Are they healthy?
4. Are you running out of disk space on the server?  Are transaction logs filling up?
5. Have you run [PerfMon](http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2006/12/dba-101-using-perfmon-for-sql-performance-tuning/) stats against SQLServer to see if there are resource pressures from I/O, CPU, RAM?
6. Are you sure the databases are identical?  Does the server have triggers that are not on your local database?
7. Are other users accessing the database simultaneously?  Are they running queries that may be blocking your query?
8. Have you updated statistics on your server recently?
9. Are you running the exact same queries in both database?  Different where clauses could be using indices completely differently.
10. Have you run an execution plan for a sample query in both databases and compared the results?
11. Are there errors in the SQLServer logs or event logs on the server?

Comment: Both databases are completely identical(no difference in triggers,etc) . Same data,same queries,same where clauses .No monitoring software are installed.The application is in test phase and only one user connects to database.In both cases the application is installed on the same computer as database is(No network issue). Enough resources(CPU,RAM,Hard,...).
None of above issues are exist.